# Looking for a early 2000s pop song with "tu tu tutu" hook

Tags: identify-this-song, pop

While listening to this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qByHiwXiBBg), I remembered an early 2000 pop song with very much the same melody (see Youtube clip at 1:30).

The hook of the song I look for, is nothing more than "tu tu tutu tututu" by a female singer. It's a bit similar to the hook "Can't get you out of my head" by Kylie Minogue.

Does someone know what this song is?

Comment: @Simon are you referring to the repeated guitar riff that starts around 1:30? If so, that's WAY older than 2000s, more  like 1970's when I can remember where it's from.

Comment: Yes, that high pitched riff. What do you think it is?

Comment: I think it might be "Rock Your Baby" by George McRae?

Comment: ...and "whosampled" confirms it http://www.whosampled.com/George-McCrae/Rock-Your-Baby/

Comment: @Lefty - If you're pretty sure that's correct, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I would - but no-one seems to care, least of all the OP.

Comment: I'm downvoting because after listening to the song referenced in the original post, and the song identified as the answer, I don't think there's any way anyone except the original poster could have made the connection, particularly since the description provided is vague and inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the song!
[Ann Lee - Two Times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbkInTnNQ28)